# ODBC driver for BigQuery connection can't authenticate even when Im using the right credentials

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to link our BigQuery data to some excel files, at the beginning it was working fine but now it always through the message that "We couldn't authenticate with the credentials provided. Please try again" or for those that I was succesfully able to connect them the first time now it shows [simba][BigQuery][ (8711) Authentication failed: invalid_grant. error_description: reauth realted error (invalid_rapt)"

I already did a research on the web and looks like this issues happens with different systems but for each scenario the solution didn't work for this, and I didnt find any question related to BigQuery but Power Bi, SQL server, etc.

Hope someone can alleviate the frustration that I have at this point

And thank you!